# How to add border to label when radio button is selected

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

```
<label for="seeker" class="checkbox">
    I am a Job Seeker
    <input type="radio" id="seeker" name="designation">
</label>

<label for="employer" class="checkbox">
    I am an Employer
    <input type="radio" id="employer" name="designation">
</label>
```

I have multiple HTML radio inputs which are wrapped around labels (https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHlDd.png) when a radio is selected for say input name "designation" I'd like to add a border color to the label of the radio button that was selected and remove the border from the other labels (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri4Pk.png), here's the the JS code I tried using but for some reason when a radio button is unchecked JS can't seem to detect the event.

```
const radios = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox input')

radios.forEach((radio) => {
    radio.addEventListener('change', e => {

        if (e.target.checked) {
            // logic to add label border
        } else {
            // logic to remove label border
        }

    })
})
```

I know this can be done using the CSS plus (+) operator but seems like that would require the label to preceded the input, something I wouldn't want to do. However I'm open to using a CSS method as long as the markup wouldn't have to be changed.

Comment: You've got some issues there already. You have no elements with class `checkbox` so your `querySelectAll` will return nothing. Your `input` is a radio button, not a checkbox besides.

Comment: @lurker I'm sorry, while trying to simply the code to post my question I forgot to include them, fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

```
const inputs= document.body.querySelectorAll("input")
    document.addEventListener("change", (e)=>{
        inputs.forEach(input=>{
            if(input.checked){
                input.labels[0].style="border-style: solid; padding: 10px;"
            }
            if(!input.checked){
                input.labels[0].style=""
            }
        })
    })
```

here is the js logic

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this code snippet. I have also provided the required styling if you want.

```js
document.querySelector(".first-checkbox").addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector(".first-checkbox").classList.add("active");  
  document.querySelector(".second-checkbox").classList.remove("active");
})
document.querySelector(".second-checkbox").addEventListener('click', function(){
  document.querySelector(".second-checkbox").classList.add("active");  
  document.querySelector(".first-checkbox").classList.remove("active");
})
```

```css
.first-checkbox,.second-checkbox{
  border:1px solid #D3D3D3;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:5px;
}
.checkbox-container{
  width:80%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  padding:20px;
  border:1px solid #C0C0C0;
  border-radius:5px;
 } 
 .active{
  border:1px solid black;
  border-radius:5px;
  padding:5px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="checkbox-container">
<label for="seeker" class="first-checkbox">
    I am a Job Seeker
    <input type="radio" id="seeker" name="designation">
</label>

<label for="employer" class="second-checkbox">
    I am an Employer
    <input type="radio" id="employer" name="designation">
</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply do it css using input:checked selector

Take an example from below code and codepen link https://codepen.io/naren-irain/pen/XWXWWqq

```css
.radiobox {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  user-select: none;
}
.radiobox input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.radiobox .check {
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #979797;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.radiobox span, .radioTab span, .checkbox span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.radiobox .check i,
.radioTab .check i {
  background: #0db837;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: -5px 0 0 -5px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
.radiobox input:checked+.check,
.radioTab input:checked+ span .check {
  border-color: #5cb85c;
}
.radiobox input:checked+.check i,
.radioTab input:checked+ span .check i {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<h4>Select any one option</h4>
<label class="radiobox" for="one">
    <input type="radio" id="one" name="designation" value="one" />
    <span class="check"><i></i></span>
    <span>This is one option</span>
</label>
<br/>
<br/>
<label class="radiobox" for="two">
    <input type="radio" id="two" name="designation" value="two" />
    <span class="check"><i></i></span>
    <span>Never think this is an option</span>
</label>
```

Comment: The OP **specifically** stated that the HTML could not be changed.